# How to get \ifcase to work with a macro argument

Tags: macros, xstring

How can I make the `\ifcase` statement accept my `\myindex` macro as an argument in the following example. On its own, the `\myindex` macro expands correctly, however, I get an error when I use it as the argument to the `\ifcase` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

\newcommand{\id}{32103210}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  \def\myindex{\StrChar{\id}{#1}} %get the #1th character from \id
  My index is \myindex\\%   <-- this works fine

  \ifcase\myindex%   <---- ifcase not working with \myindex but works with other macros
  zero \or  one \or two \or three% <--- expecting zero
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

After `\ifcase` TeX expects a `<number>` so it expands tokens, but `\StrChar` does assignments, so it doesn't purely expand to a `<number>`. Use the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\id}{32103210}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \StrChar{\id}{#1}[\myindex]% get the #1th character from \id
  My index is \myindex\\%   <-- this works fine
  \ifcase\myindex%   <---- ifcase not working with \myindex but works with other macros
  zero\or one\or two\or three% <--- expecting zero
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{4}
\end{document}
```

Be also careful with spurious spaces.

[image]

An implementation with `expl3` that has the advantage of being fully expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\id}{32103210}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
 {
  \str_case_x:nn { \tl_item:Nn \id {#1} }
   {
    {0}{zero}
    {1}{one}
    {2}{two}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand{4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `stringstrings`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings,ifthen}

\newcommand{\id}{32103210}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  \substring[q]{\id}{#1}{#1} %get the #1th character from \id
  My index is \thestring\\%   <-- this works fine

  \ifcase\thestring% 
  zero \or  one \or two \or three%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]